# Htaccess rule to turn /home/index/2 into /page/2?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Now my urls look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/home/index/2
```

What would be the htaccess rule to turn that into this?:

```
http://mysite.com/page/2
```

Note: 2 can be any number starting from 1 to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this [website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#Solutions) for reference every time I need to rewrite the url. You should probably read there too. Below is my suggestion, please modify according to your need.

```
RewriteRule ^/home/index/(.+) /page/$1 [R]
```